# C++ Undefined references?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

So this is a segment of my program, i am having trouble calling the the functions and I really need some help. It's basically to choose either function and enter data and 
    later print that data.  What am doing wrong ?please help, I keep getting

> "[Linker] reference to `Customer_Record()'" , [Linker error] undefined reference to`               `Car_Record()`'  and "ld returned 1 exit status"

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>  
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <windows.h>  
 #include <conio.h>

void Customer_Record(), Car_Record();
int num;

struct Customer {
    char customer_ID[20];
    int license;
    char address[20];
    int phone;
    char email[20];
} cust;

struct car {

    int regno[20];
    char model[20];
    char colour[10];
} car;


main() {
    printf("               Enter 1 to go to Customer Record \n\n");
    printf("               Enter 2 to go to Car Record \n\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num = 1) {
        Customer_Record();
    } else if (num = 2) {
        Car_Record();
    } else {
        printf("Invalid Number");
    }

    system("cls");

    void Customer_Record(); {
        printf("********CUSTOMER RECORD********"); /* accepts into*/
        printf("\nEnter the name of the customer ");
        scanf("%s", &cust.customer_ID);
        printf("Enter the license number of the customer ");
        scanf("%d", &cust.license);
        printf("Enter the address of the customer ");
        scanf("%s", &cust.address);
        printf("Enter the cell phone number of the customer ");
        scanf("%d", &cust.phone);
        printf("Enter the email address of the customer ");
        scanf("%s", &cust.email);
    }

    void Car_Record(); {
        printf("********CAR RECORD********");
        printf("\nEnter the car's registration number ");
        scanf("%d", &car.regno);
        printf("Enter the car's model ");
        scanf("%s", &car.model);
        printf("Enter the colour of the car ");
        scanf("%s", &car.colour);
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `void Car_Record();` declares a function.

Comment: @chris: i think that's  intended here

Comment: There is no semicolon outside the braces in a function definition.  Which should give you a compile error, not a linker error.  Please show actual code.

Comment: @AndyProwl, Look further down.

Comment: @chris: oh, right. but what's worse, that's being done inside `main()`: i would have never figured that out without copy-pasting to an IDE, +1 for the answer

Comment: @Andy, I just counted braces and said "aha". =)

Comment: @aschepler, The lack of compiler error stems from the code being in `main`. There's a function declaration, followed by a block of code.

Comment: @CarlNorum: you are a living compiler

Comment: You have a number of errors here. Notably the fact that you're using the *assignment* operator in your if statements instead of the *comparison* operator `==`.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I try. ;-)  My friend @VariableLengthCoder says that's not quite accurate, though.  I don't generate code - I'm just a parser/front-end.

Answer (score 6):

Don't nest your functions like that.  The definitions of `Customer_Record()` and `Car_Record()` should be *outside* of `main()`.  You need to take the `;` off of the definitions of those functions, too.

Try formatting your code better - that will help a lot in the long run.

Comment: separated the functions and took off the ; off the definitions of the functions but i ran into another error "expected init-declarator before "void"  Sorry for all this but i'm pretty new to this

Comment: Sorry, without seeing the new code, that's going to be hard to diagnose.  You can certainly ask a new question to follow-up.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're missing a } at the end of main, the compiler thinks your function declarations are within the main function.
2. Remove the trailing semicolon from your function. Ex:

   ```
   void Car_Record();
   {
   ```

   to

   ```
    void Car_Record()
    {
   ```

That semicolon isn't necessary.

Comment: There is a `}` at the end of `main`.  He wouldn't get as far as a linker error if he had a syntax problem like that.  You're right about the semicolon, except that it's not just unnecessary, it in fact *must not* be there.

Comment: Carl, Good point. The getchar calls just blended together in with the functions when I read it.

Comment: Yeah the original formatting was pretty bad, which made it hard to see.

Answer (score 1):

I've compiled a list of all the problems with your program. Here it is:

- Your if statements are using the assignment `=` operator when they should be using the comparison operator `==`.  So for example, change the following:

  ```
  if (num = 1) {
  ```

  to

  ```
  if (num == 1) {
  ```

  This also occurs in your `else` statement as well.
- It is also incorrect to define functions inside of main. You must define these blocks *outside* the main clause. You've already prototyped the functions above main, now you must define them below main. In addition, you shouldn't have a semicolon after the parameter list when defining functions; that is syntactically wrong.

The following is advice. You're compiling this code as C++ but this is written using C functions/headers. In order to convert it to C++, do the following changes:

- **Change your headers:** stdio.h, conio.h, stdlib.h; these are all C-style headers. Essentially all headers that end in ".h" are C-style headers. C++ has its own I/O library, thus making its C equivalent obsolete. Include the following headers instead:

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cstdlib>
  ```

  I left out additional headers because it seems you're only using `printf`/`scanf` and `system`, the equivalent of which C++'s `iostream` and `cstdlib` headers already possesses. For example, `std::cout` and `std::cin` for iosteam. And the equivalent of `getchar` is std::cin.get()`.
- **Main returns int:** In standard C++, you cannot elide the return type. Specify the return type of main as `int`, but you don't have to put `return 0` at the end (this is implicit).

If you want to look up C++ functions and containers (like `std::cout`/`std::cin`), [this reference](http://cppreference.com) helps a lot.